# confusion of View Helpers

Tags: zend-framework

I'm on shared hosting where www only accessible by web server , so I change the structure recommended for the project based ZenFramework putting the library under the folder www :

www/
index.php
application/
Modules/
front/
admin/
  Library/

the .htaccess :

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

I tested locally under WampServer, everything works fine.

when I go online, I get errors on View Helpers :

Warning: include_once(): Unable to access /home/www/application/Modules/front/views/helpers/HeadMeta.php

there is confusion between ZendFramework views helpers and the view helpers that I create myself. and when I copy the content :
library \ Zend \ View \ Helper \
to
\ application \ modules \ front \ views \ helpers
everything works fine ! and it is the same concern for module admin/
I do not understand how why.
is what I have to keep the View helpers with my aides custom view ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

**Update:**

I have not attached and any help create by myself . but I have to create action helpers, like this:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/Modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule ="front"
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Application_front_Controller_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/Modules/front/controllers/helpers/"
resources.modules[]=
```

Bootstrap module :

```
class front_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap

{
    public function _initHelper()

    {

        $this->bootstrap('frontController');

        $navigation = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('NavigationPath');   

        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($navigation);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Several thoughts/questions/comments:

1. It sure seems to be looking for the view helper within your Module folder. Are you attempting to call a *custom* `HeadMeta` helper developed by you, or are you are attempting to call the *standard* `Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta` helper? Have you set any helper paths in either `Bootstrap` or `application/config.ini`?
2. Your current setup has a security issue: What if someone requests the url: http://exmaple.com/application/config.ini? I don't see any protection there. Note that you don't necessarily have to move all your ZF folders up in to the document root. Rather, you could push them *down* and place deny-all protection on that folder. See: [Zend Framework on shared hosting](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/). That blog post offers other approaches to ZF on shared hosting, as well.
3. Finally, when something works on Windows but doesn't work on Linux, there are [several usual suspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634151/why-this-code-is-not-working-on-linux-server/4637652#4637652) to check.