# Zend framework deployment on the shared hosting

Tags: zend-framework

I want to deploy my project made in zend framework to my shared hosting.
My project has such structure:

application
docs
library
Obsolete
public
scripts
tests

This is what I have done:

1. I copied Zend folder (all library files) into library folder
2. I copied all the structure above into public_html/projects/project 
   (so if I type www.mydomain.com/projects/project/public I run the project
3. I tried to click on some link so that it redirected me to www.mydomain.com/projects/project/public/someController/someAction

Unfortunately all i see is a white, empty page. 
Locally (using Zend server CE) it worked perfectly
Here it looks like Zend doesn't recognize that it should do anything with this url and redirecto to appropriate action.

What have I missed?
Greetings!

Comment: First thing is to change the `application.ini` settings for display exceptions and display errors so you can debug. Also, note these typical gotchas between Windows dev environments and Linux production environments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634151/why-this-code-is-not-working-on-linux-server/4637652#4637652

Comment: Did you set up correctly your RewriteBase in your .htaccess? It may be needed since your are running your application from within a folder which is not your webroot.

Comment: @Boris Indeed, I solved the problem with changing the RewriteBase. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see empty page instead of errors is that `error_reporting` is probably off by default on your production server.

You may change the settings concerting displaying errors and exceptions in `application.ini`.

The other cases the errors are not displayed is something goes wrong in the view (eg. view helpers), which must return string, not the exception.

Things to check:

- paths
- include_path
- permissions to write for files/dirs which do require this
- PHP version
- .htaccess setup

Answer (score 1):

stating the obvious here but I'd check your apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the server is running php as a module or CGI, in the later case it will not read the `SetEnv` of .htaccess and you will have to set to development mode in index.php by hand, or specify your config in php.ini