# Unable to install Zend Framework web application on a Linux Server running Parallel Plesks Panel

Tags: zend-framework, shared-hosting, plesk

Im trying to install a simple Zend Framework based web application on a Linux Server running Parallel Plesks Panel.

I did installations using Cpanel ...which was quite straight forward (uploading the zf app to the remote server using ftp client, changing db details in application.ini ) .. and thats it I can see my app up and running on the remote server. I tried doing the same using Plesk panel .. but the application goes blank.. i dont see any error message either.

Am I missing anything here ? Kindly guide me howto troubleshoot this prob.

FYI: Its a shared hosting and i dont have access to root console to run commands.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't see error messages because of phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0 or
phpSettings.display_errors = 0 settings in the application.ini.

Comment: Indeed. See this question for ideas on deployment gotchas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795944/zend-framework-deployment-on-the-shared-hosting

Comment: I have changed these settings to                  phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

Comment: I could access the httpd 'error log'. There i could find this error

"PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'parse_ini_file() has been disabled for security reasons' 
If I have to create xml version of the config file, how do i do that ? If I create a xml format using the method listed in the following link.. then what next? How do i make the framework understand where the new xml file is stored and this xml file has to be used in place of the old one ?
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.7/en/zend.config.writer.introduction.html

Comment: [Here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Config-Using-XML-File-Configuration-P563.html) you can read about diff types of config files in ZF application.

Comment: @Swiftguy To use an XML config file in your application, simply edit the `index.php` file and change the second parameter in the `Zend_Application` constructor to point to your XML file, eg `$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.xml');`